# Google AdMob account can't login

Tags: login

I made a new AdMob account about 5 days ago. Now I am seeing notice that I can't use AdMob at this time, with no warning or error indication such as account disabled suspended etc. Please check the screenshot. Should I create a new account or what?

[[image]

Answer (score -2):

May be u did invalid click s  lead to account suspended or disable